# Silverlight ListBoxItem Poor Performance

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have list of object which i loop around and create controls from. i then put each of these controls into the content of a listboxitem and add it to a list box.

I seem to be getting very poor performance doing with. ive commented bits of my code out and it seems that if the content is filled with a control performance goes out the window. Creating 80 of these list boxes seems to take 4 minutes Any one know why or how i can solve this?

code sample:

```
foreach (var service in e.Result)
            {
                ListBoxItem lbi = new ListBoxItem();
                lbi.Tag = service.ServiceId;

                SmallServicePanel ssp = new SmallServicePanel();
                ssp.DisplayText = service.DisplayText;
                ssp.ServiceTemplateId = service.ServiceTypeId;
                ssp.ServiceId = service.ServiceId;
                ssp.HexColor = service.HexColor;

                lbi.Content = ssp;
                MyListBoxControl.Items.Add(lbi);
            }
```

Comment: 80 (!) ListBoxes in one dialog? What a nice little dialog ;-)

Comment: unfortunately thats what the client wants, its used to be filtered down but they want an "all" option.

Comment: I too have experienced this issue, the whole UI freezes while it loads those usercontrols into the listbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than create the controls iteratively (which is slow for many controls) use binding to collections and a DataTemplate to show your display objects (`SmallServicePanel` etc.).

Once you have this in place it will use the virtualization feature of the ListBox (or choose another control that provides virtualisation). That means that the number of actual controls that exist will not be much more than what is displayed and performance will take a leap forward.

Let us know how you go.